# PDO Connection not showing all errors

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I'm having trouble getting errors to display with when making a new PDO connection.  It only shows an error if I put the incorrect password in my config file.  It won't show errors for an incorrect database name, username, or host.

```
<?php
// config file
return [
    'driver'    =>  'mysql',
    'host'      =>  'localhost',
    'database'  =>  'query_test',
    'username'  =>  'root',
    'password'  =>  '',
    'options'   => [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false
    ]
];

// connector file    
use PDO;

    class MySqlConnector implements ConnectorInterface
    {
        public function connect(array $config)
        {
            extract($config);
            $dsn = "mysql:{$host};dbname={$database}";
            $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
            return $connection;
        }
    }
```

I've tried using try/catch blocks as well as setting ini display errors and error reporting E_ALL.  Can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
return $connection;
```

to:

```
try {
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
return $connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked a simple mistake.  I had "mysql:{$host}" instead of "mysql:host={$host}".

Sorry for the silly mistake but thank you for your answer!